# Content Builder Image Taggin

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

Is it possible to tag images in content builder? I don't see the option when uploading and also not after an image has been uploaded. Is that function only in regards to templates?

Comment: There is also an Einstein feature that tags your images automatically. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_einstein_content_tagging.htm&type=5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in this help doc: [Nested Tags](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_nested_tags.htm&type=5)

> IMPORTANT Tagging to raw files like images is unavailable until the January 2020 release.

Comment: Thank you, just a little longer then. It's weird though, I don't see that line in the doc.